# Registration in Django

Tags: python, django

Can you say, is this a bad code for registration in Django? Do I need to fix something or use a pip instead? (I am learning)

```
def register(request):

    error_messages = {}

    if request.POST:
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()

            user = authenticate(username=request.POST["username"], password=request.POST["password1"])
            login(request, user)

            return redirect('index')
        else:
            form = UserCreationForm()
            return redirect('register')

    return render(request, 'account/register.html',
            {'title': 'Registration', 'error_messages': error_messages})
```

Answer (score 1):

From what you can find on the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in) you are pretty close. I may change a couple things a little just to be on the safe side:

Change:

```
user = authenticate(username=request.POST["username"], password=request.POST["password1"])
```

To:

```
user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], form.cleaned_data['password1'])
```

The first way is not wrong, but using validated data on forms is a better practice than using the raw post request. Is better to be consistent.